# Function Keys don't work

Tags: 12.04, function-keys

I know this is a commonly asked question, but some function keys dont work (Fn + F5, F6, C, V and Space). I got the **Asus eeePC F201E-KX067DU** which came shipped with *Ubuntu 12.04 LTS* and after the first boot-up every function key was working out of the box. I changed the OS to *Ubuntu 12.10* and since then some Fn keys didn't work anymore (I also tried installing *12.04 LTS* again to see if those keys work again).
I already searched for some hours now, without any results ... editing /etc/default/grub with:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nosplash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

or

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nosplash acpi_osi="
```

doesn't seems to work.